# Add letter to second/third/fourth occurrence of a string?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a large text file that looks like this:

```
1   1:49298 0   49298   T   C
1   1:54676 0   54676   T   C
1   1:54676 0   54676   A   G
1   1:86028 0   86028   C   T
1   1:86028 0   86028   T   G
1   1:86028 0   86028   A   G
1   1:91536 0   91536   T   G
```

The second column contains some multiples - there are definitely duplicates and it is possible that there are triplicates etc, but I have not explored this fully.

I would like to add the letter 'b' to the end of the second occurrence in column 2, and 'c' to the third occurrence, 'd' to the fourth occurrence, and so on. So the output file should look like this:

```
1   1:49298 0   49298   T   C
1   1:54676 0   54676   T   C
1   1:54676b    0   54676   A   G
1   1:86028 0   86028   C   T
1   1:86028b    0   86028   T   G
1   1:86028c    0   86028   A   G
1   1:91536 0   91536   T   G
```

I thought this could be done using awk, but I have not yet figured out any viable options.

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail? Is Perl an option? (It has a convenient feature so that `$x = "a"; ++$x` results in `$x` containing the string "b".)

Comment: What should be added to the 27th occurrence? How about the 53rd?

Answer (score 3):

This MIGHT be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk 'cnt[$2]++ { $2=sprintf("%s%c", $2, 96 + cnt[$2]) } 1' file | column -t
1  1:49298   0  49298  T  C
1  1:54676   0  54676  T  C
1  1:54676b  0  54676  A  G
1  1:86028   0  86028  C  T
1  1:86028b  0  86028  T  G
1  1:86028c  0  86028  A  G
1  1:91536   0  91536  T  G
```

Answer (score 2):

another `awk` which will let you control the codes you append

```
$ awk -v codes="$(echo {b..z})" 'BEGIN{split(codes,s)} 
                                      {$2=$2 s[c[$2]++]}1' file | column -t

1  1:49298   0  49298  T  C
1  1:54676   0  54676  T  C
1  1:54676b  0  54676  A  G
1  1:86028   0  86028  C  T
1  1:86028b  0  86028  T  G
1  1:86028c  0  86028  A  G
1  1:91536   0  91536  T  G
```

Answer (score 1):

Or perl:

```
perl -lane '
    $F[1] .= chr(96 + $count{$F[1]}) if $count{$F[1]}++ > 0;
    print join "\t", @F
' file
```

Answer (score -1):

And also this:

```
awk '{if ($4 == previous) {i++; print $1, $2sprintf("%c", 97+ i),$3,$4,$5,$6} else {previous = $4; i = 0; print;}}' file
1   1:49298 0   49298   T   C
1   1:54676 0   54676   T   C
1 1:54676b 0 54676 A G
1   1:86028 0   86028   C   T
1 1:86028b 0 86028 T G
1 1:86028c 0 86028 A G
1   1:91536 0   91536   T   G
```